# What exactly represent these parameter of this function associated to a form submit event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, javascript-framework, impromptu

I am pretty new in JavaScript\JQuery and I have the following doubt about this code found in a project on which I am working on.

This project use **jQuery Impromptu** plugin to show dialogs: http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/

So in my JavaScript code I have something like this:

```
function salvaDatiContabili(ente){
    if($('#gestioneDatiContabiliForm').valid()){
        $.prompt('I dati contabili inseriti possono essere associati a tutti i tuoi progetti per l\'ente '+ente+'. A quali progetti vuoi associare i dati inseriti? ', {
            title: "Richiesta di conferma",
            position: { width: 700 },
            buttons: { "Solo a questo progetto": "progetto", "A tutti i progetti per l\'ente beneficiario": "ente", "Annulla": "annulla" },
            submit: function(e,v,m,f){

                if(v!= 'annulla')
                    alert('chiamata ajax: '+v);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The **$.prompt()** function of this code render a dialog with 3 buttons, respectivelly with the following content text: **"Solo a questo progetto"** and **"A tutti i progetti per l'ente beneficiario"** and **"Annulla"**.

My doubt is related on the meaning of the **e,v,m,f** of the function associated to the **submit** event by this code:

```
submit: function(e,v,m,f){
    if(v!= 'annulla')
    alert('chiamata ajax: '+v);
}
```

I have understant that the **v** parameter identify the value associated to the action of the clicked button.

But what exactly represent the other 3 values? Are something related only to the **jQuery Impromptu** plugin or are some generic JQuery or JavaScript stuff?

Comment: I'd say it's a `jQuery Impromptu` specific thing - From the page you linked it states the parameters are `event, value, message, formVals`

Comment: Had you considered reading the manual? https://www.evernote.com/l/AAOI7MJApcVPiKNuiDTR4szQlE63HcvUWes